# How to setup web app with custom domain name as SSL on heroku?

Tags: ssl, heroku, hosting, web-hosting, domain-name

I have a web app and trying to host it on Heroku. I also bought the domain name on name.com. Everything works locally just fine. It also works with URL  "app.herokuapp.com." But when I add DNS mapping, enable SSL, and try to go by my link, I have an error that IP is not found. Can anybody say what I did wrong?
UPD: Okay, I did everything one more time, and now it works, but only with HTTP, even though I enabled automatic SSL.
Screenshot:
[image: Heroku settings]

Comment: Please post screenshots of your DNS mapping and the error you see when visiting your URL.

Comment: This [project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) contains detailed instructions. Most likely you either added custom domain in Heroku dashboard to your app without adding CNAME to your custom domain's registrar DNS settings. Or other way around, you added CNAME to registrar's DNS without adding custom domain to the app in Heroku dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot. I managed to solve my problem. I don`t know where the issue was, but I just removed all records from DNS in Heroku settings and added it one more time. And added default SSL support. Everything works.